# Laravel - método para actualizar datos de un modelo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

tengo un modelo que es Company , y su controlador CompanyController quiero hacer la operación de poder actualizar los datos de un registro para ello hago lo siguiente

**Ruta**

```
Route::put('companies/{company}','Api\CompanyController@update');
```

**Controlador**

```
public function update(Request $request, Company  $company)
{
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'enabled' => 'required',
]);

$company->update($request->all());

if ($company === null) {
    return response()->json('Company Not found', 404);
}

return response()->json($company, 200);
}
```

Realmente me devuelve un 200, pero no me actualiza los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bueno tenía pensado...que si el modelo tiene 4 propiedades...si les pasas dos actualice esas dos

Comment: si retornas una vista con el method dd() ? para pruebas retorna el mismo resultado ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cómo puedes leer [en la doc. De Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#updates) el método update espera un *array con los valores a actualizar*, mismo que capturas con esta sintaxis:

```
$request->all();
```

Sin embargo al momento tu consulta no funciona y deberías considerar que:

- En ella aparte de los datos que haya modificado el usuario esta viajando el token generado por *`@csrf`* como puedes apreciar en este ejemplo:

---

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "FTwNsFwBY8eEWJK2gbibxCU6VElHAGMuRwAjdG7s"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "title" => "algo"
  "NUMERO" => "11111"
]
```

Lo cual te generaría un error como este al momento de intentar realizar el *`update`*:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list'

Lo que en este punto puedes hacer es:

**Opción 1**

- Utiliza alguno de los métodos [`only` o `except`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input) para indicar cuales son los valores que esperas permanezcan en el `$request` o cuales no, de esta forma:

  ```
    Modelo::query()->update($request->only('uno', 'dos'));
  ```

**Opción 2**

- Acceder a los valores que tiene el objeto `$request`  (*sin el método all o eso lo transformaría a un array*) por medio de sus propiedades dinámicas de esta forma:

  ```
    Modelo::query()->update([
                             'clave1' => $request->valor1,
                             'clave2' => $request->valor2
                           ]);
  ```

**Puntos finales**

- De esta forma no se estaría intentando insertar el `_token` en alguna de las columnas y puedes tomar los valores del `$request` para proceder con tus modificaciones.
- Esta actualización que estas llevando a cabo es general sobre todos tus registros, deberías considerar el uso de `where` para establecer *donde debe esto actuar* o corres el riesgo de perder datos por una modificación masiva.

Toma con consideración este ejemplo para el último punto que te menciono:

```
Modelo::query()
        ->whereId(1)
        ->update($request->only('uno', 'dos'));
```

Comment: esta opción es valida pero si hago => $company->update(['name' => $request->valor1, 'color' => $request->valor2] ); y solo le paso en el request el 'name' el color que me lo pondrá a nulo?

Comment: Alguna vez he visto una opción que actualice los valores que recibe por request, algo tipo esto 

$book->update($request->only(['title','author', 'description']));

Comment: Gracias @BetaM , tenia el problema en el modelo puse fillable = ['*'] y eso no me funcionava...puse las propiedades una a una y entonces si.

Comment: @ilernet edité la respuesta incluso atendiendo al punto que me mencionas sobre el uso de `only` te invito a revisarla

Answer (score 1):

Para actualizar un registro lo hago por medio route model bilding, el return es la vista de una formulario para editar los campos.

```
 public function editCompany(Company $company){

    return view('users.companies.edit', 
        compact ('company'));
    
}
```

La ruta para ver y editar:

```
Route::get('/company/edit/{company}', [CompanyController::class, 'companyEdit'])
->name('company.edit');
```

El método update puede ser así:

```
 public function companyUpdate(CompanyRequest $request, Company $company)
{
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $input = $this->companyInput();
        $company->fill($input)->update();

        DB::commit();
         session()->flash("message", ["success", __("Modelo acutalizado satisfactoriamente")]);
        return redirect(route('home'));
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {

        DB::rollBack();
         session()->flash("message", ["danger", $exception->getMessage()]);
        return back();
    }
}
```

Si algo falla es mejor obtener un error a no saber que paso, por eso mismo es mejor hacer una beginTransaction y obtener los algún mensaje ya sea afirmativo o de error.

El método companyInput() es el siguiente:

```
protected function companyInput(): array {
    return [
        "name" => request("name"),
        "enable" => request("enable"),
        
    ];
}
```

Puedes crear tu propio CompanyRequest y defnir tus reglas de validación:

```
 switch ($this->method()) {
        case "POST": {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|min:10|unique:companies', 'enabled' => 'required',
            ];
        }
        case "PUT": {
            return [
                'name' => 'required|min:10',
            ];
        }
        default: {
            return [];
        }
    }
```

Así tus controladores tendrán un código más limpio.